# Pass special character as argument

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
strcat(arg1, argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", arg1);
```

It's working well, but when I pass argument like "$$" I got number in output, not dollar sign. What is simplest explanation and solution?

example.

```
./main.bin "$$$"
```

output:

```
8789
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you did with this code? You describe what you did without showing it. This examle is incomplete.

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: ./main.bin "$$$"

Comment: try `char arg1[256] = "";`

Comment: I have tried, it's not that.

Comment: My guess this is a shell-related issue rather than a C issue.  Try either `./main.bin '$$$'` or `./main.bin "\$\$\$"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix shells such as bash, `$$` is a variable containing the current process id. Use `'$$'` or `\$\$` to prevent shell variable expansion.